# Select tag in javascript not calling onchange hander function

Tags: javascript

My javascript code is :

```
var headerCell = document.createElement("TD");

var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
var select = document.createElement("select");
select.innerHTML = '<select id ="ddl" onchange="somekdfj()"><option value="0">wow</option><option value="1">pls</option></select>';

frag.appendChild(select);
headerCell.appendChild(frag);
row.appendChild(headerCell);
```

javascript function:

```
function somekdfj(){        
    alert("HI");
}
```

I am new to this. Could anyone please tell me why I am not able to call javascript function above?

Comment: I could be easier to debug your code if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below line is incorrect in your code :

`select.innerHTML = '<select id ="ddl" onchange="somekdfj()"><option value="0">wow</option><option value="1">pls</option></select>';`

Reason : Here you are changing the **innerHTML** of **select** tag, which is not going to bind event like **onchange**. In order to do that you can change this piece of line to below :

```
 select.setAttribute("onchange","somekdfj()");
 select.setAttribute("id","ddl");
 select.innerHTML = '<option value="0">wow</option><option value="1">pls</option>';
```

Comment: thnak you so much  forgot to add but  select = document.createElement("select"); was commented in my code and only select.innerHTML = '<select id ="ddl" onchange="somekdfj()"><option value="0">wow</option><option value="1">pls</option></select>'; was in my code but it was not working. you are right sir bind event not work like this. thank again:D

Comment: If you comment `select = document.createElement("select")` then where you want to add innerHTML, in that case you should use, `headerCell.innerHTML`

Comment: yep i just changed this much and it's working     headerCell = document.createElement("TD");

 headerCell.innerHTML = '<select id ="ddl" onchange="somekdfj()"><option value="0">wow</option><option value="1">pls</option></select>';
row.appendChild(headerCell);

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the select elements correctly, since within a select element you are adding another select element and the `onchange` is on the inner element causing a problem. Try it in th below manner, if you are going by the `createElement` approach or else you can directly set the `innerHTML` to the parent element where you are appending the created elements

```
headerCell = document.createElement("TD");

 frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
 select = document.createElement("select");
 select.id="dd1";

 frag.appendChild(select);
 headerCell.appendChild(frag);
 row.appendChild(headerCell);

 var options = [{val: 0, text: "wow"}, {val: 1, text: "pls"}];

 for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
     var option = document.createElement("option")
     option.value=options[i].val;
     option.text=options[i].text;
     select.appendChild(option);
 }

 select.onclick=somekdfj;
```

Comment: thank you so much now i have one more approach in my hand

Comment: I will advice you to use this approach, as it will be easier to expand your application if you have to add more values to input and since you are using createElement approach your should be following it thorughout